# Anyone using La Pavoni EDL Eurobar Deluxe? Comments? Reviews?

Tags: espresso, espresso-machine, coffee-machines, coffee-culture, barista

Hello Dear Coffee Experts,

I am in advance very grateful for any advise you can provide me.
I am testing an espresso coffee machine from one of my colleagues who just upgraded his.

He bought a Lelit and is now selling his 2004 La Pavoni EDL Eurobar Deluxe. Although I know it is a good brand I have been unable to find good reviews about this specific model. Does anyone have comments, reviews or advise? He lend it to me and I have been testing it for the past 3 days but I am not an expert. I wonder if at the price he is selling it to me I should take it (114 USD). I was planning to buy something in the 650 USD range but if this is an incredible deal then please let me know.

Thanks again and I look forward to your knowledgeable advise,

Jose

Comment: You say he lent it to you for the past few days, what was your experience with it? How did the coffee taste and did you have fun using it?

Comment: I ended up buying it from him. The quality of the machine surprised me. Créma is thick and the coffee is absolutely delicious. I am very satisfied for the price I paid.
I need to explore different coffee grinds to see what suits the machine best. Thanks for asking.

Comment: That's great! You should consider creating an answer for your own question with more detail so people who stumble upon it know about your experience with it!